# Quitar extensión de archivo php

Tags: php

Tengo una duda que no sé solucionar. No veo qué estoy haciendo mal.
He creado este código para que se muestren unos archivos .pdf y .pptx en una página pero los archivos se muestran con su extensión y busco que se muestre el nombre solo sin extensión.

```
function show_resources($resources){?>
    <div class="row">

    <?php
    if($resources->num_rows > 0 ){
        while($row = $resources->fetch_assoc()) {?>
        <div class="mt-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card bg-transparent border-secondary h-100 m-auto" id="pdf">
            <?php
            $extension = pathinfo($row, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $logo = '';
                if(strpos($row["file_name"], '.pdf') !== false){
                    $logo = 'pdflogo.png';
                }elseif(strpos($row["file_name"], '.pptx') !== false){
                    $logo = 'pptxlogo.png';
                }
                if ($logo) { 
                    echo '<img class="card-img-top imgrecursos" src="../../assest/images/'.$logo.'">';
                }
                ?>
                        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                            <h5 class="card-title text-center"><?php echo pathinfo($row["file_name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)."\n"; ?></h5>
                            <div class="mt-auto text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary mx-auto" href="<?php echo "../".$row["file_path"]; ?>" target="_blank">Descargar</a></div>  
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("No data in database!");
                }?>
    </div>
            <?php

            }
                ?>
```

Tengo creada esa función que funciona bien y me muestra los archivos pero he intentado usar el pathinfo para quitarle la extensión y me funciona al revés. Solo me muestra la extensión y no el nombre.
¿Alquien tiene alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El segundo parámetro de `pathinfo` es para especificar lo que quieres que devuelva, le estás enviando `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` y por eso muestra solo la extensión. Remplaza con `PATHINFO_FILENAME` para obtener el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Un saludo